What are the White fuzz on blades of grass
What are the white fuzz on the grass blades.  I have a picture but cant figure out how to include it.



When editing, press the icon of mountains.

Hello, and welcome to the site.  How to post images here may help you edit the picture in.

I inserted a sample photo directly: Copy image & Paste like text. No icons.

Starting from scratch, take a picture on your cellphone, and Share it as an email to yourself. Either send it or leave it in the Draft folder. Then on your computer, Copy the photo and Paste it into your post.

Weird comment section. I always click Edit->Browse->[select a file on my computer]. @OP +1 quite interesting. Could we get a super macro shot of the white stuff?
